# Kivy app not detecting touch events when using cv.VideoCapture()

Tags: python, kivy, event-handling

I am working on a Kivy app. At some point, the user will have to touch the screen to indicate where the corners of a tennis court are. I want to take the coordinates of this touch, and create a ROI. I did this using OpenCV easily:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2 as cv
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

cap = cv.VideoCapture('partido/06_centro.mp4')
cv.namedWindow("Video")

def get_roi(frame, x, y):
    roi_corners = np.array([[x-50, y-50], [x+50, y-50], [x+50, y+50], [x-50, y+50]])
    mask = np.zeros(frame.shape[:2], np.uint8)
    cv.drawContours(mask, [roi_corners], 0, (255, 255, 255), -1)
    return cv.bitwise_and(frame, frame, mask=mask)

def mouse_callback(event, x, y, flags, param):
    if event == cv.EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN:
        roi_frame = get_roi(frame, x, y)
        cv.imshow("ROI Frame", roi_frame)


cv.setMouseCallback("Video", mouse_callback)

while True:
    ret, frame = cap.read()

    cv.imshow("Video", frame)
    
    key = cv.waitKey(1) & 0xFF

    if key == ord('q'):
        break

cap.release()
cv.destroyAllWindows()
```

This code works, but now when I try to do the same with Kivy I can show the video but it doesn't recognize the touch event (the `print` statement is not executed):

```
import cv2
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.graphics.texture import Texture
from kivy.clock import Clock
import numpy as np


def get_roi(frame, x, y):
    roi_corners = np.array([[x-50, y-50], [x+50, y-50], [x+50, y+50], [x-50, y+50]])
    mask = np.zeros(frame.shape[:2], np.uint8)
    cv2.drawContours(mask, [roi_corners], 0, (255, 255, 255), -1)
    return cv2.bitwise_and(frame, frame, mask=mask)

class VideoPlayerApp(App):

    def build(self):
        self.image = Image(allow_stretch=True, keep_ratio=False)
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.update, 1.0/30.0)
        self.cap = cv2.VideoCapture("./partido/06_centro.mp4")
        return self.image

    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        print("Touch down")
        if self.image.collide_point(*touch.pos):
            x, y = touch.pos
            x = int(x / self.image.width * self.cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH))
            y = int(y / self.image.height * self.cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT))
            ret, frame = self.cap.read()
            if ret:
                roi_frame = get_roi(frame, x, y)
                cv2.imshow("ROI Frame", roi_frame)

    def update(self, dt):
        ret, frame = self.cap.read()

        if ret:
            buf = cv2.flip(frame, 0).tobytes()
            image_texture = Texture.create(size=(frame.shape[1], frame.shape[0]), colorfmt='bgr')
            image_texture.blit_buffer(buf, colorfmt='bgr', bufferfmt='ubyte')
            self.image.texture = image_texture

    def on_stop(self):
        self.cap.release()
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()
        
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = VideoPlayerApp().run()
```

I'm still using the method `VideoCapture()` from OpenCV, and I'm updating the Image component using `schedule_interval`. I started using Kivy recently, so I can't find the error. Can you help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `App` class does not handle `on_touch_down` events, so your `on_touch_down()` method will never be called. The `Image` class, however, does handle `on_touch_down` events (all `Widgets` do). So you can bind to that event using your `Image` in your `build()` method, like this:

```
    self.image.bind(on_touch_down=self.on_touch_down)
```

And modify that `on_touch_down()` method to accept the correct arguments:

```
def on_touch_down(self, image, touch):
    print("Touch down")
    if image.collide_point(*touch.pos):
        x, y = touch.pos
        x = int(x / image.width * self.cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH))
        y = int(y / image.height * self.cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT))
        ret, frame = self.cap.read()
        if ret:
            roi_frame = get_roi(frame, x, y)
            cv2.imshow("ROI Frame", roi_frame)
```

Note that in this method you can replace `self.image` with just `image` since it is an argument passed to the method.